# Convert a unicode object to a latin string with entities

Tags: python, unicode

I have a unicode object like

```
x = u"a & 日本語:  enči hallöle"
```

and want to convert it into a latin-1 string with html-entities like

```
"a &amp; &#26085;&#26412;&#35486;: en&#269;i hallöle"
```

the reason behind this is, that I want my users to be able to enter unicode data, but my legacy database where I need to save my data only accepts latin-1 strings. (the "ö" should not be converted, but the other special characters must be converted)

Any idea which module to use here? I searched through the encoding module, looked up some codecs, tried a bit with methods of unicode objects, but came to no sensible solution.

Comment: I would store the UTF-8 bytes as Latin-1 characters with the same number, and do the charset conversion in the data access layer. Gives smaller results than HTML-encoding and doesn't tempt you to output straight from the database to an HTML page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `"xmlcharrefreplace"` option of `unicode.encode`, but note that it won't translate `&` to `&amp;` for you:

```
>>> x = "a & 日本語:  enči hallöle".decode("utf-8")
>>> x.replace("&", "&amp;").encode("latin-1", "xmlcharrefreplace")
'a &amp; &#26085;&#26412;&#35486;:  en&#269;i hall\xf6le'
```

Comment: thank you! that was exactly what I was looking for. (now waiting 7 minutes until I can check your answer als "accepted")

Answer (score 0):

Just encode your to UTF-8, that should be save.

```
>>> x.encode("UTF-8")
'a & \xc3\xa6\xc2\x97\xc2\xa5\xc3\xa6\xc2\x9c\xc2\xac\xc3\xa8\xc2\xaa\xc2\x9e:  en\xc3\x84\xc2\x8di hall\xc3\x83\xc2\xb6le'
```