# Convert unicode symbol to unicode entity

Tags: python, perl, unicode

I have been searching SO for a suitable solution on how to convert a Unicode symbol (ἔ) to it corresponding Unicode entity (&#x1F14;). I have a text file which contains lot of such symbols like ῶἤÜὰὔ. I am looking for a python or even Perl script which can take the file as an argument and process each symbols and write its equivalent Unicode entity in an output file. I saw similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112621/convert-a-unicode-object-to-a-latin-string-with-entities) but it was dealing with html entity.

Comment: there aren't two different things called unicode entities and html entities, they are the same

Comment: For example instead of &amp;#7956; [HTML Entity (hex)] i need &amp;#x1F14; [HTML Entity (decimal)].

Comment: why?  they are equivalent

Comment: I know both are same. But, my requirement is &amp;#x1F14; and not &amp;#7956;.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 3.3+:

```
#coding: utf8
import re
s = 'abcῶἤÜὰὔdef'
s = re.sub(r'[\x80-\U0010FFFF]', lambda x: '&#x{:04X};'.format(ord(x.group(0))), s)
print(s)
```

- `re.sub` uses a regular expression and a replacement function.
- `r'[\x80-\U0010FFFF]'` matches a single non-ASCII Unicode character.
- `lambda x: '&x{:04X};'.format(ord(x.group(0)))` is an anonymous function that receives the regular expression match.  `x` is the match object.  `x.group(0)` is the substring that matched.  `ord` gives the Unicode ordinal number of the character, and `format` generates the required html entity string as the replacement.  The lambda expression is equivalent to the function:

```
    def replacement(matchobj):
        substring = matchobj.group(0)
        unicode_value = ord(substring)
        return '&x{:04X};'.format(unicode_value)
```

Output:

```
abc&#x1FF6;&#x1F24;&#x00DC;&#x1F70;&#x1F54;def
```

Comment: This is perfect. Can you please write what is doing here.

Answer (score 4):

`perl -Ci -0777 -E 'print map {sprintf "&#x%04x;", ord $_} split(//,<>)' foo.txt`

Comment: Is there a way the ascii characters were not changed in the process. Also, could you please elaborate the process done here.